# Restart explorer without executing start up items

Tags: winapi

This is the small AutoHotKey script I use to restart explorer:

```
WinGet, h, ID, ahk_class Progman
PostMessage, WM_QUIT, 0, 0, , ahk_id %h%    
Run, explorer.exe
```

The problem is that it runs Start up items.
I see that this dude had [the same](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/System/Windows__Programming/Q_20733516.html) problem.

Anybody knows a way to fix it ?

Comment: Why do you want to restart explorer? Probably better to ask the user to log off/on

Comment: No, it is not irrelevant. If you have a shell extension and you need to replace it's on disk file, I know a hacky solution, it does not apply to anything else.

Comment: I am making a library function that can be used for any purpose.
So, like I said, its irrelevant :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meh...

They key is to hold SHIFT while loading explorer.exe.... Sending the key to window seems to work *most of the time*

Answer (score 1):

One ugly solution might be to temporarily modify the Startup folder path prior to restarting explorer.exe.

The registry key to modify would be:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\Startup
```